# Symfony2 and Doctrine2 - history of changes of record

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to keep in database history of changes of Profile. Except of profile data I must save timestamp and user_id. Query to create new history record is simple:

```
INSERT INTO history_profile 
SELECT NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), p.* FROM profile p WHERE p.profile_id=?
```

Where put this query? I can't use triggers. I have several ideas:

1. in controller in action called on submit form

   ```
   $em = $this->getEntityManager();
   $conn = $em->getConnection();
   if (!is_null($profile->getProfileId()))
   {
       $conn->executeQuery('INSERT INTO history_profile SELECT NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), p.* FROM profile p WHERE p.profile_id=?', array($profile->getProfileId()));
   }
   $em->persist($profile);
   $em->flush();
   ```

   but this query is executed each submit even if there is no updates to profile.
2. in entity, as event listener to preUpdate

   ```
   class Profile {
       /**
        * @ORM\preUpdate
        * @ORM\prePersist
        */
       public function onPrePersist()
       {
       }
   }
   ```

   but I don't know how to get doctrine's connection object

**edit - EntityAudit trial**

This bundle looks promising but I can't configure it. I installed it properly and when I add to config.yml:

```
simple_things_entity_audit:
    audited_entities:
        - AldenXyzBundle\Entity\Profile
```

and looked at queries after

```
php ./app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

but there was only SQL for create table revisions:

```
CREATE TABLE revisions (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I haven't used this bundle. In controller after POST form with data and flushing EntityManager I added function which copy the record directly in database (adding some revision information on the way). But I used idea with different table for revision info from the bundle.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [EntityAudit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit#entityaudit-extension-for-doctrine2) bundle for versioning your entities.

Comment: After doing `doctrine:schema:update --force` checkout the [usage](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit#usage) section. EntityAudit automatically creates revision when you save or update an entity to db.

Comment: `doctrine:schema:update --force` created only table `revisions` and not `profile_audit`

Comment: Odd. Try checking out `v0.1.0` tag.

Comment: Also I think by `AldenXyzBundle` you meant `Alden\XYZBundle`

Comment: How to manage history of changes in relation many-to-many? For example single profile belongs to many groups.. There are 2 assigned to profile and there is no generated SQL for audit tables. Also there is no entity for relationship.

Comment: Many-to-many relation is currently unsupported. See `Todo` section at the bottom of the doc.

Comment: Source is open. You get the idea :). I have used it for simple relations actually :).

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine2 has a datetime field type. Have a look at [doctrine's datetime examples](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html). However, if possible, you may want to consider letting the database handle createdOn and/or modifiedOn through it's timestamp mechanisms or triggers. Also, sql should not go in your Entities. If you need custom sql, it should go in your Custom Entity Repositories.

I'm not sure if you are looking for only "createdOn" timestamp or "updatedOn" timestamp or both. [Doctrine's versioning](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) (section 9.2.1) could be thought of and used as a "updatedOn" datetime field.

Comment: *in your repositories. Entity Manager manages already created objects.

Comment: The latter link from you is about transactions and locking. How can it be useful for me?